# Invalid object name when trying to create new table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Started with EF6 yesterday and am already frustrated.

Anyways, as far my research says, EF can create a database if it doesn't exists and can also create tables. So, i passed my connection string to my `DbContext` as follows :

```
public CampaignDbContext() : base("Data Source=xx;Initial Catalog=NewTestDb;User ID=xx;Password=xx;")
{ }
```

My models and the entire DbContext class is most likely irrelevant here so that's why i am not adding the code. Anyways, my model class is called `Campaign` and inside the DbContext class, i have declared the obvious :

```
public DbSet<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }

//Also added this
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   Database.SetInitializer<CampaignDbContext>(null);
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Now, from my test method, when i populate the `Campaigns` DbSet and call :

```
CampaignDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I got the error :

> Cannot open database "NewTestDb" requested by the login. The login failed

Once again in my programming career, i am shocked. The same credentials passed in the connection string(in the dbcontext class) works fine if in SSMS/sample sql connection from code-behind but that ain't working here. But when i create `NewTestDb` manually from SSMS, the connection was successful. Now, when i call the `SaveChanges` method of `CampaignDbContext`, i get :

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Campaigns'

I have went through tons on SO posts already and don't see anything wrong with my code. Can somebody point out where am i missing/what am i doing wrong?

P.S. I am new to EF.

Comment: Can you verify that the `Campaigns` table actually exist?

Comment: @bolkay, no i don't. isn't EF supposed to create the table ?

Comment: The error means there is a mismatch between the entity name and the name of the table in your database. Please verify this in SMSS.

Comment: @bolkay, i recreated the database , it is entirely empty. one more question , why EF doesn't create the db ? why the connection fails when the db is not pre-created ?

Comment: I'm not so certain what you mean but EF should create the database for you. I really recommend you check the code-first approach. You will be amazed how easy it is to work with Entity Framework.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx

Comment: @bolkay, i did follow the code first approach. My code is supposed to generate the database and the table. If you read my post carefully, you would see what i have been through.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185910/discussion-between-bolkay-and-zack-raiyan).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [bolkay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10311601/bolkay). I figured it out. Turns out i had to run these specific commands from the Package Manager Console :

```
enable-migrations
add-migration InitialMigration
update-database
```

Now, everything's working fine! 
Cheers!